# When Response.text() promise will reject?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I see that on [MDN/Response/text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text) docs show the example of using `.text()` only with `then`

```
response.text().then(function (text) {
  // do something with the text response
});
```

> It returns a promise that resolves with a String.

Because of lint rules, I need to put

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises
res.text().then(async (t) => {
```

Is there a use case when I need to catch a rejected promise from `Response.text()`? Maybe some examples?

Comment: _"The consume body algorithm, given an object and type, runs these steps: 1. If object is unusable, then return a promise rejected with a `TypeError`, ...."_, _"An object including the Body interface mixin is said to be unusable if its body is non-null and its body’s stream is [disturbed](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/#is-readable-stream-disturbed) or [locked](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/#readablestream-locked)."_

Comment: It does fail when the stream is closed or gets aborted, although I'm not certain when/if that happens. It does not fail when there is an UTF-8 encoding error, it just replaces it with U+FFFD. I also wonder if it fails if there is a `Content-Length` mismatch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can fail/reject if the response was already `consumed`/read, so i.e if something already called .text/.json etc on it.

Looking at the polyfill implementation (https://github.com/github/fetch/blob/d1d09fb8039b4b8c7f2f5d6c844ea72d8a3cefe6/fetch.js#L301 ) I don't see other likely cases though.

---

Example:

```
response.text()
  .then(t1 => {
    console.log({ t1 }); // after calling text() we can see the result here
    return response; // but we decided to return the response to the next handler
  })
  .then(res =>res.text()) // here we try to read text() again
  .then(t2 => console.log({ t2 })) // and expecting text to be logged here
  .catch(er => console.log({ er })); // but the text() promise rejects with 
  // TypeError: Failed to execute 'text' on 'Response': body stream already read
```

Comment: Doesn't documentation say that `fetch` resolves as soon as headers arrive? So in theory headers could all arrive, while during receiving a large body a network disruption could occur, so text() would throw an error because it can't receive the whole body. Is it possible?

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I'll try to setup an example and test it. I figure however that: Every amount of response-bytes (even an empty/cut one) can be interpreted as text; the headers and body are in the same range of tcp packets, likely even all the headers+start of the body in the first. I'm not sure if it checks that body.length==Content-Length header

Comment: I don't think/hope it would resolve with incomplete response-data however. The likely outcomes are: .text() throws, or the request rejects in total. But will need to be tested and likely even vary by platform